# How does Groovy select method when a user-defined method conflicts with a GDK method

Tags: groovy

I wrote the following Java classes:

```
package com.example;

class MySet extends java.util.AbstractSet {
    @Override public java.util.Iterator iterator() { return null; }
    @Override public int size() { return 0; }
}

interface ToSet { MySet toSet(); }

public class MyList extends java.util.AbstractList implements ToSet {
    @Override public Object get(int index) { return null; }
    @Override public int size() { return 0; }
    public MySet toSet() {
        return new MySet();
    }
}
```

and a test in Groovy:

```
package com.example

class MyTest {
    @org.junit.Test
    public void test() {
        MySet set = new MyList().toSet();
        println(set.class);

        println(new MyList().toSet().class);

        def set2 = new MyList().toSet();
        println(set2.class);
    }
}
```

The test run results in:

```
class com.example.MySet
class java.util.HashSet
class java.util.HashSet
```

My guess is that in the latter two cases the expression `toSet()` invokes the GDK's `toSet` method instead of `MyList#toSet`, but what is the exact rule about this behavior? Does Groovy's method selection depend not only on receiver and arguments, but also on the context?

One more subtle thing is that if I remove `implements ToSet` from the Java code above, the test prints `class com.example.MySet` for all three cases. So I got confused.

Answer (score 0):

In the three examples you mention, your toSet method is never invoked. This is easily verified by adding a print statement to your toSet method in MyList. The reason the first class is printed as MySet is because of the assignment to a variable of the type MySet - Groovy will implicitly cast the HashSet to MySet upon assignment (magic!).

The rest of the behavior is more subtle. When no interface implementation is declared (you remove implements ToSet), Groovy method dispatcher will pick the method implementation on the MyList class, i.e. the method you defined. Apparently, when the interface implementation is defined, the method dispatcher has to choose between the interface implementation (MyList toSet) and the superclass implementation (GDK toSet), and it's choosing the latter (they both have no arguments).

Comment: If GDK toSet is considered to be superclass implementation, it is still puzzling why MyList.toSet is overlooked; shouldn't it override or hide superclass implementation?